# VBA to shift graph range by one

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart which I need to update every day to shift it down by one cell. I am unable to do this using VBA. Can someone please suggest. So basically my chart has a range (Say 'VaR by LOB Graph Data'!$B$1588:$B$1838) how do I shift  it by one ('VaR by LOB Graph Data'!$B$1589:$B$1839))
using VBA? Please suggest.

Comment: Does the chart is placed on the separate sheet or as an object in the sheet?

Comment: Try using a named range and assign the data for the graph to the named range. Then you only have to update the named range for the graph to update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing how to implement dynamic chart range.

1. Populate a column of a sheet with some data.

[image: Source data]

2. Go to <kbd>Formulas</kbd>, Click <kbd>Define Name</kbd>.

[image: Define Name]

3. Enter range name and cells it refers to. Use [`OFFSET()` formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) to make chart range dynamic. Let's choose seconds to define the target range, it makes the example more spectacular. The below formula `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1;SECOND(NOW());0;10;1)` returns the range that is changing dynamically depending on seconds from `$A$1:$A$10` to `$A$61:$A$70`.

[image: Add range]

4. Insert chart to the sheet.

[image: Insert chart]

5. Click <kbd>Select data</kbd> in chart context menu.

[image: Select data]

6. Select `Series1` and Click <kbd>Edit</kbd>.

[image: Edit data]

7. Enter your new created range.

[image: Enter range]

8. Now the chart is rebuilt each time the sheet is recalculated. You can press <kbd>F9</kbd> to force recalculate and see how the chart data is moving from right to left. There is no VBA needed.

[image: Dynamically changing data]

For your case, if you need the range to be `'VaR by LOB Graph Data'!$B$1588:$B$1838` on e. g. 10 May then the formula for the named range should be `=OFFSET('VaR by LOB Graph Data'!$B$1588;TODAY()-42500;0;251;1)`. First argument `'VaR by LOB Graph Data'!$B$1588` is the cell the offset based on. Second one `TODAY()-42500` returns 0 on 10 May, that means there is no offset needed on this date, 42500 is the value of date 10 May 2016 represented as the number, you can just enter a date to a cell and apply General format to find out that number. If you have several data series, then you have to create the named range for each of them.